# Creating nested custom tag using jsp2 tag files

Tags: jsp-tags

I want to create custom jsp tags.Following is my requirement.

1.The tag I have to create can always be added as a chlild tag for certain tags.So I want to validate the tag to check if it is inside a valid parent tag.

2.I want to access the attributes of the parent tag in the child tag file and vice versa.

3.I also want to set one property for each tag which can be set from the tag file and the user should not be able to set it.

I would like to know if I can accomplish these with tag files or should I go for creating custom tags using java code? If these can be done suing tag files can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Navigating up the tag tree, which is required for the validation in your first point, is only possible inside a custom tag (implementing `SimpleTag`, and using its `getParent` method), but not in a custom tag file.

Example for checking the type of parent and setting an attribute:

```
JspTag jspTag = getParent();
if (jspTag instance MyCustomTag) {
    MyCustomTag myCustomTag = (MyCustomTag) jspTag;
    myCustomTag.setFoo("bar");
}
```